# Is it possible to have a customised Image URL Path?

Tags: url, image

We're in the middle of looking at the benefits of using Magento rather than Actinic/Sellerdeck, but one of the main problems we cannot find a way around so far is that we would need to keep our image paths as our images are referenced elsewhere, such as eBay. Under Sellerdeck all our image URLs are under one location, so for example the image "bob.jpg" will always be under "http://[site URL]/acatalog/bob.jpg".

It wouldn't be a problem for new images to have a different structure, but we need all our old products images to still be available under these URLs, there's just too many to change manually, does Magento have any support for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to find a solution within Magento. As you said, new images do not need this custom directory structure, only the old images.

I'd suggest creating the directory `acatalog` in the root and moving all your old images in here so you preserve all the old deeplinks. So basically preserving the directory structure you're currently using for your images.

The only drawback is (potentially) a lot of double files on the server since Magento needs the images to in another position but this is by far the easiest solution since it doesn't involve Magento at all.

Comment: As Sander mentioned, you could duplicate the physical files. I would also look into creating an .htaccess rewrite or even using a symlink on-disk that would direct it to the new file paths.

Comment: A dedicated directory separate from Magento is our backup plan as it is a nice simple solution which will be easy to implement. The only real drawback is as you say the duplicated data, which while it only amounts to a few gigabytes, is what we are trying to avoid if a nice solution does exist to homogenise the image links.

I didn't actually consider using the htaccess file for this, but that will be rather simple to implement with the help of Excel.

Thanks to both of you!

Comment: Let us know if you find a better / nicer solution. @philwinkle's solution with symlinks would save you those gigabytes but all in all if it's only a few it shouldn't be a problem